# Formatear variable con el tiempo de respuesta de un servicio a punto decimal con curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl, ssh

Soy nuevo en bash, y deseo utilizar el tiempo de respuesta obtenido con el comando curl para realizar diferentes operaciones.

Pero al obtenerlo en una variable, me lo formatea con coma decimal, es decir algo como #,#### pero yo lo necesito con punto decimal #.#### para, por ejemplo realizar una suma. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(curl -o /dev/null -L -qs -w "%{time_total}" www.domain.com)
```

en este caso **var** obtiene por ejemplo 0,332342, pero si quiero

```
x=1.3
```

y lo sumo con **var**

```
result=$(echo "$var + $x" | bc)
echo "$result"
```

me genera el error

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: ¿qué  localización  estás utilizando actualmente? ¿nos puede dar la salida de `locale`?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, era por la configuración regional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl` respeta la configuración regional del usuario, por lo que usa la coma como separador decimal si el sistema así está configurado (por ejemplo, si el sistema tiene la configuración `es_ES.UTF-8`).

Se me ocurren dos posibles soluciones al problema.

#### 1. Usa una configuración regional que use el punto como separador decimal

La configuracióń regional encargada de la representación de números se establece mediante la variable de entorno [`LC_NUMERIC`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_04). Puedes cambiar temporalmente el entorno de un comando usando `env` (ejemplo: `env VARIABLE='valor' comando`) o añadiendo la asignación antes del comando (ejemplo: `VARIABLE='valor' comando`).

En las configuraciones regionales [`C` y `POSIX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_04_01) se usa el punto como separador decimal. Estas configuraciones las encontrarás en todos los sistemas adherentes a la [norma POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799).

Algunos sistemas también ofrecen la configuración `C.UTF-8`, la cual es similar a las anteriores pero agrega soporte a Unicode mediante la codificación UTF-8.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='C' curl -o '/dev/null' -s -w '%{time_total}' 'https://www.example.com/'
0.090306
```

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='POSIX' curl -o '/dev/null' -s -w '%{time_total}' 'https://www.example.com/'
0.072698
```

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='C.UTF-8' curl -o '/dev/null' -s -w '%{time_total}' 'https://www.example.com/'
0.080962
```

También puedes usar la configuración regional de un país e idioma que usen el punto como separador decimal, como `en_US.UTF-8` o `es_MX.UTF-8`.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='en_US.UTF-8' curl -o '/dev/null' -s -w '%{time_total}' 'https://www.example.com/'
0.074008
```

```
$ LC_NUMERIC='es_MX.UTF-8' curl -o '/dev/null' -s -w '%{time_total}' 'https://www.example.com/'
0.078321
```

#### 2. Reemplaza la coma por el punto

Para esto, puedes usar una [expansión de parámetro](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) o `sed`:

```sh
var="$(comando)"
var="${var/,/.}"
```

```sh
var="$(comando)"
var="$(sed 's/,/./' <<< "${var}")"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tu respuesta solucionó mi problema

Comment: Buena respuesta +1.

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que la coma se utiliza para [el separador decimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal)

Es necesario comprobar los variables de entorno `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_TIME` etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ echo 6.25 | LC_ALL= LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '{ print sqrt($1) }'
2,44949
* echo 6.25 | LC_ALL= LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '{ print sqrt($1) }'
2.5
```

Puedes forzar el uso de el punto(".") como el separador con `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
URL=....

time_curl() {
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 curl    \
        --disable          \
        --silent           \
        --output /dev/null \
        --location         \
        --write-out '%{time_total}'  "$1"
}
x=1.3
var=$(time_curl "$URL")
result=$(echo "$var + $x"|bc)
echo "$result"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta ayudó a resolver mi problema